# What to write on an invitation: "Dress", "dress code", "attire", or something else?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

I'm putting together an invitation to the premiere of a play, and since many of the guests are English, it needs to be in English. This is the text, where I've just used "dress" as a place holder:

*We are very proud to invite you to the premiere of our play [name of play]!*

*Date: [specification of date]*

*Time: [specification of time]*

*[Dress]: [specification of dress code]*

*We are looking forward to seeing you there!*

I have tried googling different kinds of invitations to find an answer to my question, but I'm either very bad at finding things, or just unlucky, because I haven't found a single invitation that contains the information I'm after! So, I'm hoping you can help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either [dress](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dress)

> **dress**
> used to refer to the type of suits, shirts, shoes, and other clothes that are worn at formal occasions:
> *a white dress shirt and bow tie*

or (from [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dress-code))

> **dress code**
>
> an accepted way of dressing for a particular occasion or in a particular social group:
> *Most evenings there's a party and the dress code is strict - black tie only.*

You can also use [attire](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/attire).

One might see

> Dress code: smart casual
> Dress: black tie
> Beach attire

etc. A good source of invitation wording can be found on [Google images](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=invitation+dress+code+wording+samples&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&biw=1260&bih=645&dpr=1.46).

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I am so stupid – I did search google images, but I only searched for different kinds of invitation; I never thought to include "dress", "dress code" or anything like that in my search! I guess it's true what they say – that you learn something new every day...